# Margins and absolute position not working correctly

Tags: html, css, css-position, margins

I have a div called menu, inside it I want to have a navigation bar div and a search div. I want that the navigation stays in center of the menu div and the search div goes to the left (or right). I tried this code but when I set the position to absolute, setting navigation's left and right margins to auto doesn't work.

**CSS code:**

```
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}

.search{
        width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
        float:left;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
}

.navigation{
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="navigation"> 
        .
        .
        .
    </div>

    <div class="search">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is a position absolute needed?

Comment: because if I remove that line, navigation div sticks to the search div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want make a navigation to center of menu (stay on center). Try this :

```
.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.search{
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 1;

}

.navigation{
    width:300px; /* you can change this */
    left: 50%; /* you can change this */
    margin-left: -150px; /* you can change this */
    height: 65px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: absolute;

}
```

<kbd>[cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/0h3yorfy)</kbd>

1. First, `left: 50%`. this will move the left-hand edge of the navigation to the center.
2. use a negative left margin that’s half its width (width of navigation div : `300px`). In our example, must set `margin-left` to `-150px` to shift the box back to the right place

Update 2015

You can do it without 'position', you can use flexbox

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search{
  width: 300px;
  height: 65px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.navigation{
  width:300px;
  height: 65px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-left:220px;
}
.navigation ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.navigation ul li {
  float:left;
  margin-left:5px;
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

<kbd>[cssdeck 2](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/cxbcr52a)</kbd>

Comment: thank you! it worked! can you tell me why you've set margin-left: -150px?  how is that working? I mean why -150px?

Comment: In my style, I have set a navigation width `300px`, for balance the position of div (navigation) I should use `margin-left` half of width's navigation and set to negative. Updated answer

Comment: interesting... but I used the display:inline-block; to set navigation div's width base on it's contents. it is likely center but not exactly in the center

Comment: why is the position absolute needed? As I dont see any top/left/right/bottom ?

Comment: @AliBordbar : If you want exactly position center you can change width and margin-left.

Comment: @SrinivasYedhuri : OP need position absolute for make the navigation div stay in the center of the page.

Comment: other example position absolute and center of div http://cssdeck.com/labs/loh0wacp

Comment: Some ask why?  An example, you have a content block on top of a slideshow carousel.  While this is the suggested hack throughout the internet, it is not sufficient for responsive development.  The above solution works great if you know the exact pixel width of your container, but if you're using percentages then this solution immediately becomes obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute doesnt work with floating. you have to actually set the pixels from the left and from the top you want the absolute positioned element.

it sounds like you dont even really need absolute positioning,

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KtgBa

Comment: If I don't use the absolute, navigation div goes right after search div.And it's not possible to make the navigation div stay in the center of the page without auto or text-align:center

Comment: position:absolute has nothing to do with margins. if you want the navigation to stay in the center of the page put it as margin:0 auto;, and if you want the search to stay on the left put it as float:left;. there is no need for any position:absolute. you can still have margins without positions.

Comment: I tried what you said. The navigation div goes right next to the search div and not in middle of the page!

Comment: add a width to the navigation

Answer (score 0):

I think user2391454 has you on the right track. Position gets confusing sometimes, but leaving it out completely might help you. Take out all of your positions in your CSS and see if that works.

Let us know.

Comment: If I don't use the absolute, navigation div goes right after search div and not in center of the page

Comment: Try leaving the position for navigation but not for the other. 
Also, is there a reason the nav and search must be within a div? Because your other option is to take it out of the "menu" div and position them within the wrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case you can specify widths, Its always better to use inline-blocks instead of floats. hope this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/Bhx4Z/2/

```
    .menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;
    }

   .search{
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 1;
    border:1px solid green;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

   .navigation{
    height: 65px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align:right;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but the navigation div is not in the center of the page!